# Own "Dynamic" Vector Class

Tags: c++, class, dynamic, vector

i am having trouble making my own dynamic vector class...
the final goal is to simulate stacks and queues, with classes over a vector class, and then migrate to make stacks and queues over a linked list, on c++, 
but i am having trouble making the vector class...

because i can't make a variable with a default value, i am assigning them on the constructor, but, it seams that it doesn't work, this way... and i really don't want to use the  of the standard library 
any ideas?

my idea was to declare the array in the constructor and then copy it to the pointer declare on the class but it does int work...  i can only get the value of the first element, but not the rest...

```
    class Vector{
    private:
        int *arr;
        int size;
        int inside;
    public:
        Vector(int);
        int length();       // Largo del Arreglo
        int count();        // Numero de elementros adentro
        bool empty();       // Vacio
        bool full();        // Lleno
        int at(int);        // Revisa el N elemento
        int get(int);       // Regresa el n elemento
        bool put(int, int); // Inserta elemento X en n posicicion
        void clean();

};
/// Clase Vector
Vector::Vector(int x){ // Constructor
    int vec[x];
    arr=vec;
    size=x;
    inside=0;
}
// Estado del Vector
bool Vector::empty(){
    if(inside==0){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
bool Vector::full(){
    if(inside==size){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
int Vector::length(){
    return size;
}
int Vector::count(){
    return inside;
}
// Manipulacion de Datos
int Vector::get(int x){
    int y=at(x);
    put(0,x);
    inside = inside-2;
    return y;

}
int Vector::at(int n){
    int i=arr[n];
    return i;
}
bool Vector::put(int x, int p){
        arr[p]=x;
        inside++;
        return true;
}
void Vector::clean(){
    for(int i=0;i<length();i++){
        put(0,i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just use std::stack, std::list, std::vector at al, rather than reinventing the wheel?

Comment: Or to put it better, why don't you want to use the standard library?

Comment: @tom Perhaps. But there are sometimes also "reasons" such as "it's too slow" or "templates are too complicated" or "it uses too much memory". I've heard them all :)

Comment: @ChristianHackl Such arguments utterly amaze me sometimes. If someone *proves* in their specific task a standard container doesn't cut it for performance, ok. But I tend to lean on the side of a raft of *very* smart people that spent a *very* long time developing *very* efficient library content until such time as its *proven* otherwise (which does happen from time to time).

Comment: @WhozCraig: For the record, I think there are legitimate reasons in real life for not using it, such as when you have very large legacy code base which you cannot realistically modify due to a lack of resources and manpower needed for other projects. I think that purely technical arguments for not using it tend to be rare.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't going to work:

```
int vec[x];
arr=vec;
```

You're assigning a member variable the address of an automatic local variable that will leave scope on function exit. Accessing it from then on is *undefined behavior*. Worse, this isn't even portable, as it relies on a compiler extension for variable-length-arrays, something not support by the C++ standard.

You need to dynamically allocate your base vector using `operator new []` From that you will also need to properly implement a destructor, assignment operator and a copy constructor (and if going for the full gambit, move-assignment and move-construction) to properly comply with [Rule of Three/Five](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29) semantics.